# How to use limit, match, sort and groupby in mongo along with toInt containing strings?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have four fields `Sender`, `Recipient`, `Credit`, `Debit` in mongo collection. Of which Credit and Debit are numbers in form of strings. I need to group based on `Recipient` and add integer values of `Credit`, `Debit`. This result should be filtered as it contains non-zero and non-negative net amount, and get top three in each group based on recepient

I have database like this

```
Sender   Recipient  Credit  Debit
“Alis”   “Mike”       “6”    “-1” 
“Ajay”   “Mike”      “45”    “-31” 
“Arun”   “Mike”      “23”    “-7” 
“Arvind” “Mike”      “45”    “-41”  
“Alis”   “Mary”      “10”    “-11” 
“Ajay”   “Mary”      “10”    “-11” 
“Arun”   “Mary”      “20”    “-31” 
“Arvind” “Mary”      “10”    “-11”     
“Alis”   “Abi”       “16”    “-10” 
“Ajay”   “Abi”       “11”     “0” 
“Arun”   “Abi”       “16”    “-10” 
“Arvind” “Abi”        “6”    “-10”   
“Alis”   “Anu”       “6”     “-15” 
“Ajay”   “Anu”       “16”    “-15” 
“Arun”   “Anu”       “6”     “-15”  
“Arvind” “Anu”       “46”    “-15”
```

And I need result like this

```
Sender   Recipient  NetAmount
“Arun”    “Mike”      “16”
"Ajay”    “Mike”      “14”
“Alis”    “Mike”      “5”  
  
“Ajay”    “Abi”      “11”
"Alis”    “Abi”      “6”
“Arun”    “Abi”      “6” 

“Arvind”  “Anu”      “31”
"Ajay”    “Anu”      “11”
```

I tried to do this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        Recipient: "$Recipient"
      },
      Credit: { $sum: { $toInt: "$Credit" } },
      Debit: { $sum: { $toInt: "$Debit" } }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      Sender: "$_id.Sender",
      Recipient: "$_id.Recipient",
      NetAmount: { $add: ["$Credit", "$Debit"] }
    }
  },
  { $match: { NetAmount: { $gt: 0 } } },
  { $sort: { NetAmount: -1 } },
  { $limit: 3 }
])
```

But it didn't give the desired result.

Comment: Paste the response you got post the query, I have seen a similar question, was it from you?

Comment: your question is not clear, i think its working perfectly, see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aod7Qo-qO1T), you can add your example documents and confirm.

Comment: @turivishal I have updated the question and the sample example. Hope it might help you to resolve the query. Please let me know if still it's not clear

Comment: @Gandalf yes, but i need a still more precise work. That's why I have made a new question. Please check on this question and help me to solve

Comment: @Balaji can you provide documents in json format.

Comment: @turivishal Please find the input json over here [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/o4jtOPrEuTa) . Please let me know if you need the json format for output

Comment: there are different fields userId and techId i am not getting who is sender and recipient, anyway i have added answer you can check.

Comment: @turivishal please check the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sDfgUr01qFg). Sorry that i have messed up with the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$group` by `sender` and `recipient`, and calculate `NetAmount`
- `$gt` to get NetAmount greater than zero
- `$sort` by `NetAmount` in descending order
- `$group` by `recipient` only and and make array of documents
- `$addFields` to slice 3 documents from docs array
- `$unwind` deconstruct `Docs` array
- `$project` to show required fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        sender: "$sender",
        recipient: "$recipient"
      },
      NetAmount: {
        $sum: {
          $sum: [{ $toInt: "$credit" }, { $toInt: "$debit" }]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $match: { NetAmount: { $gt: 0 } } },
  { $sort: { NetAmount: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.recipient",
      Docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { Docs: { $slice: ["$Docs", 3] } } },
  { $unwind: "$Docs" },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      sender: "$Docs._id.sender",
      recipient: "$Docs._id.recipient",
      NetAmount: "$Docs.NetAmount"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2d7c4JEWehV)